# Como dar um disabled em um form dependendo de qual radio button escolher?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, mongodb, express.js

Boa tarde...

Tenho os seguintes radio buttons:

```
<input type="radio" name="radio1" value="entrada"> Entrada
<input type="radio" name="radio1" value="saida"> Saida
```

Tenho também os seguintes formulários:

```
 <div class="form-group">
        <label style="color:white" for="valor">Valor Entrada</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="number" class="form-control" step="any" name="valor" required ng-model="divida.valorentrada" required>
        </div>
 </div>

 <div class="form-group">
            <label style="color:white" for="valor">Valor Despesa</label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="number" class="form-control" step="any" name="valor" required ng-model="divida.valorsaida" required>
            </div>
 </div>
```

Preciso que ao selecionar a radiobutton "Entrada", o formulário "Valor Despesa" se torne disabled, e vice-versa.

Alguém pode me dar uma luz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adicione `onchange="modSaida(this)"` nos dois `radios` e adicione a função abaixo no `script`:

```js
function modSaida(i){
   campo = document.querySelector("input[ng-model='contato.valorsaida']");
   campo.disabled = i.value == "entrada" ? true : false;
}
```

```html
<input onchange="modSaida(this)" onchange="modSaida(this)" type="radio" name="radio1" value="entrada"> Entrada
<input onchange="modSaida(this)" type="radio" name="radio1" value="saida"> Saida
<br />

<div class="form-group">
   <label style="color:white" for="valor">Valor Entrada</label>
   <div class="input-group" id="entrada">
      <input type="number" class="form-control" step="any" name="valor" required ng-model="contato.valor" required>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
   <label style="color:white" for="valor">Valor Despesa</label>
   <div class="input-group" id="saida">
      <input type="number" class="form-control" step="any" name="valor" required ng-model="contato.valorsaida" required>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer o seguinte método que verifica qual radio está checado e desativa o form correspondente:

```
<script>
    function alterarDisable() {
        var radios = document.getElementsByName("radio1");
        if (radios[0].checked) {
            document.getElementsByClass("form-group")[0].disabled = true;
            document.getElementsByClass("form-group")[1].disabled = false;
        }
        else if (radios[1].checked) {
            document.getElementsByClass("form-group")[1].disabled = true;
            document.getElementsByClass("form-group")[0].disabled = false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Aí você só precisaria adicionar um onclick em seus radios para chamar o método sempre que clicar em algum deles:

```
<input type="radio" name="radio1" value="entrada" onclick="alterarDisable()">
<input type="radio" name="radio1" value="saida" onclick="alterarDisable()">
```

Só sugiro que você dê um ID único pra cada um desses elementos, fica mais organizado. Aí você poderia usar document.getElementById, que o código vai ficar mais claro.

Comment: Não deu certo aqui.
Adicionei um id ao meu form, tentei usar getElementById mas não desabilitou o form, tentei passar como parâmetro do getElementById o ng-model do meu form, mas mesmo assim não desabilitou.